# A Linear Algebra 101 book with problems and solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I am looking for an introductory linear algebra textbook for undergrads. The basics: matrices, eigenvalues, change of basis, exponents, pseudo-inversion, SVD and QR factorization. But what I really need is a good set of problems, preferably with solutions. And it would be great if it is online or an open book.
Do you know such a book?

Comment: Axler is pretty good and apparently it has a free online abridged version: https://linear.axler.net/

Comment: The abridged version is likely unsuitable for anything but quick revision. The upcoming (November 2023 I believe) fourth edition of Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right will be open access though.

Comment: Look at the Schaum outline series for problems.

Comment: @Paul, indeed, problems with solutions.

Comment: There is a problem book written by Halmos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://hefferon.net/linearalgebra/

This book covers all of the main areas one would need in a linear algebra course and I think it has a good balance between proofs and computations. A bonus is that the book, and a WORKED solutions manual, are freely available. :)

Ps: There is a YouTube playlist that goes with it by the author: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JnTa9XtvmfI